# Beat Detektion: Detecting audio from app and produce a wave or bar for that audio... Just like Winamp or Windows Media Player

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I am trying to understand the concept of Beat Detektion and I found that it works on the basis of detecting sound through Microphone. So, my first question is will it not be a disadvantage if i am detecting sound from Microphone? Because when we are using the device it happens that other sound from environment is also there so the actual beat will not produce for sound.

My second question (actually where i got stuck) I found that this Beat Detektion is not able to access iPod Library. Will i be able to play beats if i fetch the song from ipod Library in my app and then i use with beat detektion.

http://www.cubicproductions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=67&Itemid=82

http://www.gearslutz.com/board/product-alerts-older-than-2-months/457617-beatdetektor-iphone-app-open-source-algorithm-bpm-detection.html

I will be very thankful if any reference/link other then above provided to understand Beat Detektion more...

**Edit 1**

I have got the code for the above from [this link](https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicVR)  But this code is in C++ and there it is written that we have to convert the code to XCODE project using [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/) software. I am somehow able to convert the code to xcode project but then i am only having cpp files then how should i run the program in iphone???

Comment: Please do specify why negative voting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I am somehow able to solve my problem with the Apple's [sample code : AurioTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)

I have implemented song in that example and produced the beats of the song on the basis of the beats.. In Iphone we can access sound beat using mic only. So aurioTouch uses same for beat detection